# jquery FullCalendar wrong day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I just setup a running jquery Fullcalendar.
But I notice that the calendar shows a wrong day.
Today is 2014-03-21 (Friday) and It is saying that it is Saturday (Sab in italian)

[image]

FullCalendar version is 1.6 (the latest).
This is the setup of the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                    header: {
                    left:   'title',
                    center: '',
                    right:  'prev next '
                    },

                    defaultView: 'month',
                    firstHour: 8,
                    weekMode: 'variable',
                    aspectRatio: 2,
                    editable: true,
                    ignoreTimezone:false,

                    contentHeight:950,
                    monthNames:

['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo','Aprile','Maggio','Giugno','Luglio','Agosto',
                                'Settembre','Ottobre','Novembre','Dicembre'],
                        monthNamesShort:['Gen','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mag','Giu','Lug','Ago',
                                'Set','Ott','Nov','Dic'],
                        dayNames:

['Luned&igrave;','Martedì','Mercoledì','Giovedì','Venerdì','Sabato','Domenica'],
                    dayNamesShort:['Lun','Mar','Mer','Gio','Ven','Sab','Dom']


    }); // end fullcalendar
```

The problem is independent of events: I tried also without any loaded event.

Comment: Please add what your event array looks like for this event and fullcalendar version.

Comment: You need to post some javascript code in order to be helped.

Comment: I will check, but the year printed by fullcalendar says "2014"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `dayNames` must start from Sunday as per en-us locale, so change your arrays accodingly in:

```
dayNames:

['Domenica','Luned&igrave;', 'Martedì', 'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì', 'Venerdì', 'Sabato'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven', 'Sab']
```

Ref: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/dayNames/ and http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/dayNamesShort/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/4MSYZ/

Comment: Thank you! But: there is a way to force fullcalendar starting from Monday and ending with Sunday?

Comment: @giuseppe You can set the firstDay property, see here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/firstDay/

Comment: Perhaps I lost my eyes... why I did not see that?? Thank you!